How to save as Blob the displayed image with object-fit: cover property
I have an image in my Vue.js component with the following HTML:
<img :src="thumbnail" style="height: 165px; width: 290px; object-fit: cover;">

The image is displayed with the object-fit: cover CSS property. I need to capture and save exactly what is shown on the page (with the cropping effect) as a Blob using JavaScript.
I've searched online for solutions, but I haven't been able to find anything useful.
Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Screenshot?  check

It would be nice to use html2canvas library, but object-fit is in the list of  "Unsupported CSS properties".

@FedericodiGeronimo yes, you'll have to do the calculation yourself and draw the relevant part of the image.

@AHaworth got it, so the question now is: how can I do this calculation and draw the image I want?

in that list of unsupported properties, "object-fit" is a link to an entire discussion on the html2canvas github with many users posting their workarounds

@FedericodiGeronimo well, you have to do the calculation, based on the relative aspect-ratios of the element you want to fill and the actual image - ie basically what object-fit: cover would have to do. Then draw the correct portion on the canvas.
